# perl IPC::run passing arguments seems to fail

Tags: perl, email, grep

I've been googling this for a while now, and have looked at a bunch of stackoverflow things. Issue is, I still don't have an answer and have tried all of the methods I found so far. I need grep to get those 4 lines after the match, and I'm getting unexpected behavior and errors.

Here's my perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'first';  use Data::Dumper;
use IPC::Run 'run';
my $look;
my $file = 'reject.txt';
my @result;
my @args;

#my $from = first { /From:/ } @arr;
#my $to = first { /To: / } @arr;
#my $subject = first { /Subject:/ } @arr;

open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
while (<>) {
#print $fh $_;
$look = $_;
print $fh $look;
}
close $fh;
print 'doing grep now:'. "\n";

push(@args,"-iA 4 \"forwarded message\"");
push(@args,$file);

print Dumper(\@args) . "\n";

run [ "grep", @args ], ">" , \my $output;

print $output . "\n";

print 'done with grep' . "\n";
```

And grep's output should be

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: <email@address.com>
Date: Fri, Oct 4, 2013 at 9:35 AM
Subject: New Voicemail Message from (407) 221-0727
To: recipient@here.us
```

But the result of running that perl script against a forwarded email is:

```
macpro:perl test macpro$ ./reject.pl email
doing grep now:
$VAR1 = [
          '-iA 4 "forwarded message"',
          'reject.txt'
        ];

grep: Invalid argument

done with grep
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. As I mentioned, I'm clueless about perl, just now started.

**Fix:** See @hobbs's reply below. Additionally, for a simpler semantic use for noobs, this other option works too, and you don't have to mess around with arrays:

```
use Capture::Tiny 'tee';
my $output = tee { system( "some command" ) };
```

Comment: `-iA`, `4` and `'"forwarded message"'` should be 3 separate arguments, not 1.  It's no wonder that grep gets confused.

Comment: @tjd, thank you, the error is gone, but $output gets nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push(@args,"-iA 4 \"forwarded message\"");` is wrong. You want to write:

```
push @args, "-iA", "4", "forwarded message";
```

so that those appear as three separate arguments to grep.

Comment: **That's it**. The only difference between your fix and @tjd's is the double quotes around the array item. When you **omit double quotes**, grep likes it. So I'm guessing IPC::Run takes care of having everything double quoted for grep to work with. Thank you both!

Comment: @user2872895 quoting arguments and splitting on whitespace is a shell convention. IPC::Run *isn't going through the shell*, so you pass the arguments exactly the way you want the program to receive them.